# How To Check what the user has Entered and compare it with the database values

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012

```
    string abc = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connectionName"].ConnectionString;

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(abc);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT UserName ,Password from [Login] WHERE UserName =@usern AND Password = @pass", con);
    con.Open();

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@usern", username1.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", TextBox9.Text);
    try
    {
        //if user iputs = to the values in my DB

        Response.Redirect("Userinfo.aspx?id=" + username1.Text);
    }
     //if user iputs != to the values in my DB
    catch(SqlException ex)

    {
       //error
        Label1.Visible = true;
    }
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
```

It goes with try statement even if the user inputs != to the values in my DB

Comment: On which parameter user inputs `!=` ? And why do you think your _try statement_ shouldn't work if the user input `!=` ? I don't understand this part. You are executing your `SqlCommand` at the end by the way. I think it is too normal to work your `try` part.

Comment: When I enter a wrong values I want it to show me an error, when I enter some values which are in My DB I want it to proceed.